# What's the Minimum System Spec Recommended For Developer Laptop

Tags: laptop, cpu, memory

I'll be regularly running Visual Studio 2010 Professional, SQLServer Express, Office and at least 1 virtual environment running a Linux Distro. I want the machine to be snappy and responsive even when doing a reasonable amount of Development work. I want to spend what it takes for this, but I don't want to go overboard spending more than I need to. I won't be playing many games or graphics processing so i won't need a monster of a machine.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Dual Core x64 processor, anything over 2.4GHz should be grand.

Any HDD larger than 200GB

802.11a/b/g/n

As much ram as you can afford

Screen bigger than 15.4"

Comment: PLus I'd strongly recommend a 7200rpm harddisk - makes a **huge** difference over 5400 or 4500rpm disks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you want to use VS2010, you will indeed need a bit of CPU power and RAM, it is quite wasteful there (even more so if you additionally use ReSharper. I would even recommend two cores then.)